# promise .then() not working in Electron.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, electron, es6-promise

I have function in renderer which allows user to save json data. The access to root system occurs in electron's main.js file. I wanted that message about successful saving of json data would be only shown, after its completion. For that I used `promise` `.then()` method, which theoritically should be working fine, but I am struggling to understand what is wrong.

```js
//renderer.js
function concatAndSave() {
  let dataArray = jsonArrLeft.concat(jsonArrRight);
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.electron.saveJson(dataArray);
    resolve("JSON data saved successfully!");
  });
  promise.then((info) => {
    closeSaveConfigWindow();
    const currentTime = new Date();
    textArea.value +=
      info +
      "[" +
      currentTime.getHours() +
      ":" +
      currentTime.getMinutes() +
      ":" +
      currentTime.getSeconds() +
      "]" +
      "\n\n";
    textArea.scrollTop = textArea.scrollHeight;
    removeStars(tableLeft.querySelector("#mf-table-body"), unsavedLeft);
    removeStars(tableRight.querySelector("#mf-table-right"), unsavedRight);
  });
}

// main.js

ipcMain.on("saveJson", (event, data) => {
    saveJSONToFile(data);
});

function saveJSONToFile(data) {
  const options = {
    title: "Save JSON File",
    defaultPath: "data.json",
    filters: [{ name: "JSON Files", extensions: ["json"] }],
  };

  dialog
    .showSaveDialog(win, options)
    .then((result) => {
      if (!result.canceled) {
        const filePath = result.filePath;
        const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

        // Write the JSON data to the selected file
        fs.writeFile(filePath, jsonData, "utf-8", (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
          } else {
            console.log("JSON data saved successfully.");
          }
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to construct a Promise, `window.electron.saveJson` will return a Promise and that's what you need to use for `.then()`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, there's indeed promise inside of the `saveJSONToFile`, which is in main.js, but this promise doesnt work in renderer.js, i.e. putting after `window.electron.saveJson(dataArray).then()` results in my case with error.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @Phix the stupidiest so far: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`

Comment: `window.electron.saveJson(dataArray)` just triggers the saving, it does not wait for it. You are resolving the `new Promise` immediately, regardless what *main.js* does or when it is finished or whether it errored.

Comment: @Bergi yea, you're right, there's no sense in implementing promises in renderer. The way I corrected the code, is by sending signal from main.js (via `contextBridge`) to renderer.js, so that it triggers automatically and thereafter logs the message.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in comments (and then I realized that as well) there was no waiting from `main.js`, i.e. it was only triggered once and that's all.

So I changed my code a bit and added new channel in `contextBrige` in `preload.js`:

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", {
  jsonSuccess: (data) => {
    ipcRenderer.on("jsonSuccess", data);
  },
})
```

which is called from `main.js` from `function saveJSONToFile(data)`:

```js
// FYI: look the original function in the question
fs.writeFile(filePath, jsonData, "utf-8", (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    win.webContents.send("jsonSuccess", true);
    console.log("JSON data saved successfully.");
   }
});
```

```js
function concatAndSave() {
  let dataArray = jsonArrLeft.concat(jsonArrRight);
  window.electron.saveJson(dataArray); // let it do the rest in main.js
}

window.electron.jsonSuccess((e, data) => {
// triggers only from main.js in case of successful saving
  if (data) {
    closeSaveConfigWindow();
    const currentTime = new Date();
    textArea.value +=
      "JSON data saved successfully" +
      "[" +
      currentTime.getHours() +
      ":" +
      currentTime.getMinutes() +
      ":" +
      currentTime.getSeconds() +
      "]" +
      "\n\n";
    textArea.scrollTop = textArea.scrollHeight;
    removeStars(tableLeft.querySelector("#mf-table-body"), unsavedLeft);
    removeStars(tableRight.querySelector("#mf-table-right"), unsavedRight);
  }
});
```